# How to delete a comment that is nested inside of a post, which is nested inside of a topic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

## I am trying to delete a comment that is nested inside of a post. Said post is nested inside of a topic. I am fairly new to RoR and try to work on things my own before asking question, really need help here. My current setup deletes the entire post instead of the  *comment*

### **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :users, only: [:update]

  resources :topics do
    resources :posts, except: [:index]
  end

  resources :posts, only: [] do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

### (model) topic.rb

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

### (model) post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :topic
end
```

### (model) comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
 belongs_to :user
end
```

### comment_controller

```
def destroy
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

 authorize @comment
  if @comment.destroy
   flash[:notice] = "Comment was removed"
   redirect_to [@post.post, @post]
  else
   flash[:notice] = "There was an error removing comment"
   redirect_to [@topic, @post]
  end
end
```

### part being rendered on views/posts/show

```
link_to "Delete", [@topic, @post], method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this ?"}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should change this

```
link_to "Delete", [@topic, @post], method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this ?"}
```

to this

```
link_to "Delete", [@post, @comment], method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this ?"}
```

So the link gives you a path like posts/:post_id/comments/:id with the DELETE http method.

And the controller of comments to:

```
def destroy
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

  authorize @comment
  if @comment.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Comment was removed"
    redirect_to @post
  else
    flash[:notice] = "There was an error removing comment"
    redirect_to [@topic, @post]
  end
end
```

I just changed the first redirect_to because I don't know why would you use redirect_to [@post.post, @post]

Answer (score 0):

The part being rendered on views/posts/show I would expect to delete the whole post.

If there is a comments view, you might have something like this for show with the route updated to whatever yours is, I took a guess:

```
link_to 'Delete', post_comment_path(@post, @comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

alternately, if you have an index view for comments this might work:

```
link_to 'Delete', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

Also, this section of the Rails Guides may be helpful: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Good luck!

Comment: Are you saying i need a views/commments/show? I currently do not have one at all. The instructions stated to only allow destroy routes :destroy and :create

Comment: You might not need to set up the views but regardless I think you'd need a different delete route for a comment, something similar to `post_comment_path(@post, @comment)`. If it's deleting the whole post the delete button on the comment is linking to deleting the whole post.

Comment: I tried your above solution in the comment, and then received the "Coudnt find topic without an ID error" it show the post ID and the comment ID in the URL but no topic ID, is this something to do with my redirection under my destroy method for comments?

Comment: Maybe...you could also try post_comment_path(@topic, @post, @comment) depending on what the trace was showing. You can also use the gem better errors https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors to get a more readable error and a terminal window to try different options to get different errors/see what works.